# ValueError at /like/ Field 'id' expected a number but got ''

Tags: django

I have a like button that worked fine before and now has stopped working

```
@login_required
def like(request):
    post_id = request.GET.get("likeId", "")
    user = request.user
    post = PostForNewsFeed.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    liked= False
    like = Like.objects.filter(user=user, post=post)
    if like:
        like.delete()
    else:
        liked = True
        Like.objects.create(user=user, post=post)
    resp = {
        'liked':liked
    }
    response = json.dumps(resp)
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type = "application/json")


 <button class="btn btn-info" id="{{ post.id }}">
            {% if post in liked_post %}
            <a
              href="{% url 'post-like' %}"
              style="color: white"
              id="likebtn{{ post.id }}"
            >
              Unlike</a
            >
            | {{post.likes.count}} {% else %}
            <a
              href="{% url 'post-like' %}"
              style="color: white"
              id="likebtn{{ post.id }}"
            >
              Like</a
            >
            | {{post.likes.count}} {% endif %}
          </button>
```

urls.py:

```
path('like/', views.like, name='post-like'),`enter code here`
```

When I click the like button I get the error:

```
ValueError at /like/
Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programming\NewProjecttoReviseAllTechnologies\Django Social Networking Website\djangoNewEnv - Blog Project Before 

    Buddies\django\mysite\feed\views.py", line 154, in like
        post = PostForNewsFeed.objects.get(pk=post_id)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 424, in get
        clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 941, in filter
        return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
        clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
        self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1391, in add_q
        clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1413, in _add_q
        split_subq=split_subq, check_filterable=check_filterable,
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1345, in build_filter
        condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1191, in build_lookup
        lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 25, in __init__
        self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 77, in get_prep_lookup
        return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1827, in get_prep_value
        ) from e
    ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.
    [13/Jun/2021 13:01:43] "GET /like/ HTTP/1.1" 500 181410
```

Comment: Please post complete error trace and related files. In the url tag you call 'post-like' but you only show the path for 'post-detail'

Comment: I have included now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url path should include an `id` parameter:

```
path('like/<int:id>/', views.like, name='post-like')
```

and in your view, we can work with:

```
@login_required
def like(request, id):
    user = request.user
    post = PostForNewsFeed.objects.get(pk=id)
    liked= False
    like = Like.objects.filter(user=user, post=post)
    if like:
        like.delete()
    else:
        liked = True
        Like.objects.create(user=user, post=post)
    resp = {
        'liked':liked
    }
    response = json.dumps(resp)
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type = "application/json")
```

since you use an `id` parameter in the view function.

You need to pass the id in the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<!--                           ↓ add the id of the post -->
<a href="{% url 'post-like' post.id %}" style="color: white" id="likebtn{{ post.id }}">
```

The same should happen to your other `{% url … %}`s in the template that point to the `post-like` view.

Normally however actions with side effects should be done through a POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE request, not a GET request. So it makes more sense to make a "mini" form that makes a POST request.

Comment: I have changed to what you said and get the following error:- TypeError at /like/6/
like() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Comment: @sly_Chandan: you need to alter the signature of the `like` function, see edit.

Comment: it works now...but the problem is I am getting the json response on browser with {"liked": false}

Comment: @sly_Chandan: you will need to make an AJAX request to prevent that. If you click on a link, then the browser will fetch that page, and render that page and thus no longer show the old one. Furthermore as said in the answer, you will need to make  POST request with AJAX.

Comment: @sly_Chandan: see for example https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Comment: I dont want to make an ajax request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233706/discussion-between-sly-chandan-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: @sly_Chandan: well then the browser will simply render the response of the HTTP request. This is actually one of the main reasons why AJAX is used. To make *asynchronous* calls to the webserver.

Comment: @sly_Chandan: *what* error? Did you submit the CSRF token as well?

Comment: lets discuss on chat